# ideas on how to take an email attachment (.csv), parse and insert into SQL DB automatically?

Tags: email, csv, asp-classic, vbscript, ado

The case I have is the following and I'm looking for any help someone can give as to how to approach it:

Currently, I upload a csv file to the server, then the server parses it and insert its contents into an SQL database.

What I'd like is to be able for an email with the csv attached to trigger the same kind of process (ie. move the file to a folder on the server, parse and insert)

I'm currently working in ASP with vbscript. My initial guesses lead me towards powershell and scheduled tasks.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a service like CloudMailin to receive the email at the ASP.net app and process it in the same way as before. Alternatively you could set up a task to poll for the message and then process the contents but this will obviously incur polling delays.